# Laravel Pusher error: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

In my laravel app I'm getting the following error message from Pusher, i'm a bit lost on what the error exactly means bit it seems to be triggered on this Pusher method:

```
Pusher\\Pusher->trigger(Array, 'App\\\\ Events\\\\ NewC...', Array, Array)
```

The error message and the stack trace

```
[2023-09-03 23:39:53] production.ERROR: First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): First parameter must either be an objec
t or the name of an existing class at /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php:538)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'First parameter...', '/var/www/woolov...', 538, Array)
#1 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php(538): property_exists(NULL, 'channels')
#2 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php(125): Pusher\\Pusher->trigger(Array, 'App\\\\
Events\\\\NewC...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(77): Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'App\\\\Events\\\\NewC...', Array)
#4 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager))
#5 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#6 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(653): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#9 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#10 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent))
#11 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent))
#12 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php(119): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent))
#14 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(320): Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager->queue(Object(App\\Events\\NewChatEvent))
#15 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(243): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->broadcastEvent(Object(App\\Events\\NewChatEvent))
#16 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/PendingBroadcast.php(72): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch('App\\\\Events\\\\NewC...')
#17 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(218): Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\PendingBroadcast->__destruct()
#18 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/app/Notifications/NewChatNotif.php(57): broadcast(Object(App\\Events\\NewChatEvent))
#19 /var/www/wooloveapp.com/app/Notifications/NewChatNotif.php(29): App\\Notifications\\NewChatNotif->load()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array with the url of the channel, I believe. Instead of passing either an Object or `SomeClass::class` which will pass a string. However, some reason it seems to need it in a different format or type.